# Avoid repositioning elements in d-flex or alternative

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to add elements linearly with equal spacing between them. I am able to achieve with Bootstrap 5 flex which I directly use.

[image]
e.g. of linear elements(they aren't spaced equally, I want them equally)

Ass soon as I change text length of button, the space changes and elements are repositioned. How to prevent that and change/reposition only affected part?

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center vh-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-baseline pt-3">
          <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Button 1</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Button 2</button>
          <input type="range" class="volume-range" min="1" max="5" step="1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var buttonTextChanged = false;
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!buttonTextChanged) {
    button1.innerText = "Some large text";
    buttonTextChanged = true;
  } else {
    button1.innerText = "Button 1";
    buttonTextChanged = false;
  }
});
```

[image]

As in image, although they are equally spaced, they are repositioned after text size change. How can I align axis, increase text size but still other items position shouldn't change?

Options other than d-flex are also fine,

Answer (score 1):

Try `justify-content-between` instead of `justify-content-evenly` in that column.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline pt-3">
  <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Button </button>
  <input type="range" class="volume-range" min="1" max="5" step="1">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried `justify-content-between`. Start and last element position stays at its position but other element changes their position. Here's an [image](https://imgur.com/ipaXmzI)

Comment: When I copied your code onto a blank Bootstrap page it did spread everything out equally with `justify-content-between`. I am wondering if perhaps you have some CSS detailed somewhere which could be affecting the position? Do you have any CSS for position, margins or padding for `button` or for any of these `btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg`. Naturally I just had your HTML with no CSS affecting it.

Comment: I have nothing in my css file, just html and js which I shared above except html, body tags and default bootstrap 5 css. Will test again in clean browser and let you know

Comment: It was all evenly spaced for me on your original code inc `justify-content-between`

Comment: I tried `justify-content-between` and it is working. Not sure why it wasn't initially.